# How do I find the limit of this exponential expression?

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone tell me in detail how to solve the following limit? I do have the solution to it from WolframAlpha but I cannot understand it:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \log\Bigl(1+\frac{2}{x}\Bigr)^x$$

Comment: Do you know the limit of the expression inside the $\log$?

Comment: log(1)=0 as x goes to infinity

Comment: True. But the inside doesn't approach $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the inside of the $\log$ is:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+{2\over x}\right)^x$$

Which is the limit definition of $e^x$:

$$e^x = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n$$

Where $x=2$. Thus the inside of the logarithm approaches $e^2$. Then, you can take the $\log$ from there.

Comment: now got it. thanks.

Comment: @jax That's the limit definition of $e^x$, where $x=2$. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

You want
$\lim_{x\to\infty} \log\Bigl(1+\frac{2}{x}\Bigr)^x
=\lim_{x\to\infty} x\log\Bigl(1+\frac{2}{x}\Bigr)
$.

But
$\log(1+z)
=\int_0^z \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
\le z
$
since
$1+t \ge 1$
and
$\log(1+z)
=\int_0^z \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
\ge \dfrac{z}{1+z}
= \dfrac{z+1-1}{1+z}
= \dfrac{z+z^2-z^2}{1+z}
= z-\dfrac{z^2}{1+z}
$
since
$1+t \le 1+z
$.

Therefore
$x\log\Bigl(1+\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)
\le x\frac{a}{x}
=a
$
and
$x\log\Bigl(1+\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)
\ge x\left(\frac{a}{x}-\frac{(a/x)^2}{1+a/x}\right)
=a-\frac{a^2}{x+a}
$.

Therefore,
since
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^2}{x+a}
=0$,
$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\log\Bigl(1+\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)
=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the use of the classical formulae involving the exponential functions, just consider
$$ A=\log \left(\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)^x\right)=x\log \left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)$$ and remember that, using Taylor series (or even equivalents)
$$\log(1+\epsilon)=\epsilon -\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ Since $x\to\infty$, make $\epsilon=\frac a x$ to get
$$A=x \left(\frac{a}{x}-\frac{a^2}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) \right)=a-\frac{a^2}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ whci shows the limit and also how it is approached.